# Edges of u'v' color space (calculating boundary of transformed 2D space)

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, linear-transformations

I'm trying to parametrize the boundary of the [u'v' color space (CIE1976; see image below)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELUV)*.  I know the transformations to go from RGB color space, and I know the boundaries of the RGB space.  How does one calculate the boundary of the transformed space?  The space is,

$$
u' = \frac{4X}{X + 15Y + 3Z} \\
v' = \frac{9Y}{X + 15Y + 3Z}
$$

Where, 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
X \\
Y \\
Z \\
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0.49 & 0.31 & 0.20 \\
0.17697 & 0.8124 & 0.01063 \\
0.0 & 0.01 & 0.99 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
R \\
G \\
B
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

And: $R,G,B\in[0.0, 1.0]$

[image]

*Really, I want the boundary of u'v' space, but parametrized in terms of RGB... but I think I can handle the reverse transformations to get that part.

---

For example, for red:

RGB $ = [1, 0, 0]$
XYZ $ = [0.49, 0.1769, 0.0]$
u',v' $ = [0.623, 0.506]$

which is the right-most point on the triangle.

Comment: There appears to be a misconception here. The CIE chromaticity diagram is not the boundary of the color space per se. You need the data that generate the diagram in the first place or a description of its boundary in *some* color space. Once you have that, then transforming it into some other color space (which amounts to choosing a triangle in $rg$ chromaticity space) should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: I don't follow what you're saying.  The 'data' to generate this diagram is the transformation and parameter space I've described.  I'm looking for the boundaries of this diagram --- i.e. the edges of the colored, triangular region.

Comment: The chromaticity diagram is only a piece of the entire color space.

Comment: As well, if you apply the mapping that you’ve presented to an RGB vector of $(1,0,0)$ or $(0,1,0)$ the resulting points fall outside of the colored region. Indeed, per this transformation the region of $u'v'$ space that corresponds to RGB values in the range $[0,1]$ is a triangle.

Comment: @amd 1) Of course this is only a piece of all color space, I mean, it's only 2D after-all.  In particular it has the Z coordinate suppressed... although I'm not entirely sure how that's interpreted.  Anyway, it *doesn't matter*, I'm looking for the edges *of **this** color space*.   2) You're incorrect for the R, G, and B vectors... I just went through their transformations.  I added the red example to the question itself.

Comment: If you only consider $R,G,B\in[0,1]$ you will only obtain a triangle, as shown in this figure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space#CIE_RGB_color_space (albeit in a slightly different colour space). The boundary of the chromaticity diagram contains *all* colours in the visible spectrum, many of which cannot be represented as a convex combination of the RGB primaries.

Comment: Yes, I made an arithmetic error there. That doesn’t change the fact that the image of the RGB cube under this map is a triangle that’s contained within the chromaticity diagram, and not the pictured shape.

Comment: You can generate plots of various color space gamuts overlaid onto the chromaticity diagram in Mathematica with the built-in `ChromaticityPlot` function. There’s a substantial region of the visible spectrum outside of the RGB triangle. The CIE RBG triangle is larger, but still a subset of the full spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

The image of the unit RGB cube under this mapping is a triangle that falls within the pictured area. As Rahul points out in his comment, the RGB gamut doesn’t cover the entire visible spectrum. To generate the boundary of the pictured area, you need other data besides the RGB-to-u'v' transformation.

It’s not hard to see that the image of the unit RGB cube is a triangular region in u'v' space. The XYZ-to-u'v' transformation is a perspectivity that maps lines through the origin (less the origin itself) in XYZ space to a single point in u'v' space. The RGB-to-XYZ mapping transforms the unit cube into a paralellepiped with a vertex at the origin and planes through the origin in XYZ space are mapped to lines in u'v' space so the boundary of the image is a triangle.

Indeed, writing the RGB-to-u'v' as $$\mathbf p_{u'v'} = \begin{bmatrix}4&0&0\\0&9&0\\1&15&3\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0.49 & 0.31 & 0.20 & 0 \\ 0.17697 & 0.8124 & 0.01063 & 0 \\ 0.0 & 0.01 & 0.99 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}R\\G\\B\\1\end{bmatrix} = \mathtt A \left[\begin{array}{c|c} \mathtt M & \mathbf 0 \end{array}\right] \begin{bmatrix}R\\G\\B\\1\end{bmatrix}$$ followed with a dehomogenization of $\mathbf p_{u'v'}$ by dividing through by its last component, makes it recognizable as a pretty standard pinhole camera projection with the camera at the origin. The linear part $\mathtt{AM}$ of this projection could be refactored into the product $\mathtt{UR}$ of an upper-triangular and orthogonal matrix and $\mathtt U$ normalized for a more conventional factorization of this projection into intrinsic and extrinsic matrices.